# Insert line in a specfic line in a file

Tags: python

I have a very simple question but I don't find the answer ...

I have a file (data.txt) it contains

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I just want to make function to insert line where I want in this file.

Like : Insert('Bouh', 3)

Render :

```
A
B
C
D
Bouh
E
F
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: What does the second argument in your function `Insert()` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

UPD: '\n' is already included as the last symbol, so like this

```
lines = open('demo.txt', 'r').readlines()
position = 3
lines.insert('other line\n', position)
with open('demo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```